Surprising but confusing ML results
can anyone help me in understanding the following issue, please?
I am working on anomaly detection using supervised machine learning technique. I am surprised and badly fed-up with results, as for one dataset it is outstanding and for other, these are worse.
The issue is, "False positive rate is 100%, simultaneously True positive rate is 99%." To my knowledge, this should not happen, the case should be otherwise i.e. if TPR is 100% then FPR should be 0%.  What do you say? What could be the possible reason of getting such results?
For better understanding, the screenshot is attached, please.
I have tried to tune my model using different values in the range 0-4 for different datasets. The model showed encouraging results in one case and discourages for another dataset.

TPR and FPR are not directly related mathematically. But TPR - FNR = 100%, which holds in your example.
